# How to create animation which animate repeatedly with UIViewPropertyAnimator?

Tags: swift, ios-animations, uiviewpropertyanimator

with the UIView.animate: method , we can configure the options and make it [.autoreverse,.repeat]. *here is a simple Animation*:

```
@IBOutlet weak var v1: UIView!
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse,.repeat], animations: {
                self.v1.frame = self.v1.frame.offsetBy(dx: 100, dy: 0)
            }, completion: nil)
```

this code will animate the v1 moving it forward and back repeatedly, how can I do it with UIViewPropertyAnimator?(*I want to the the advantage of stop and pause*)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418128/repeating-and-reversing-an-animation-multiple-times-using-uiviewpropertyanimator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewPropertyAnimator` doesn't provide a way to do repeated animations. You need to use the old `UIView` animate class methods.

Comment: You can always restart it in the completion block 